# How can I list certain types of my Tag class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I'm having trouble listing a `Dogs` tags as I want them to be. There's 3 different `tag_types` on my `Tag` class, which are red, blue and green.

```
class Tag
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :dogs, through: :taggings

 TAG_TYPES = %w(Red Blue Green)

 validates :tag_type,    inclusion: { :in => TAG_TYPES }
end

class DogsController
  def index
    @dogs = Dog.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
  end 
end
```

I'm searching for a `Dog` and it can have all 3 tag types on it. I would like to list the last 3 added tags for each type separately like this:

**dogs/index.html.erb**

```
<% @dogs.each do |dog| %>

    <% dog.tags(:tag_type => "Red").last(3).each do |tag| %>
       <%= tag.name  %>
    <% end %>

    <% dog.tags(:tag_type => "Blue").last(3).each do |tag| %>
       <%= tag.name  %>
    <% end %>

    <% dog.tags(:tag_type => "Green").last(3).each do |tag| %>
       <%= tag.name  %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I tried this but it list any tag no matter the color so all the results for listing 3 tags are the same. How could I just show the correct ones for each block?

Comment: can you try this `dog.tags.where(tag_type: "Red").last(3)`

Comment: @Thahakp Yes, this simple change made it work. Could you make this an answer instead? I would like to give you credit. Thank you.

Comment: Not need. Your comment is more than enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thahakp the simple change was to add `where` to `dogs.tags`.